# Still can't mount Windows 8 drive after restart

Tags: dual-boot, mount

After following the instructions in other posts, I am still getting the same error when I try to mount my Windows 8 drive in Ubuntu 14.04 on a dual boot system. I have disabled fast start after shutdown, hybrid hibernation, and the preinstalled Asus Instant On service. I have tried restarting Windows rather than shutting down. In all cases I get the same error message:

> Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/jesse/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/jesse/OS"` exited with non-zero exit status 14: `Windows is hibernated, refused to mount`.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
>   The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>   Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>   read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

I did not have the same issue before upgrading from Ubuntu 12 to 14.

For what it's worth my computer is supposedly a "hybrid" with an SSD drive installed, although I can't see that the SSD drive is being used at all with my present settings. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you don't need to write on the Windows partition, you can mount it as read-only by executing in the terminal: `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda4 -o ro` (*sudo* not required). Of course, this doesn't answer your question, but you may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had been able to do the read only mount, but needed to be able to save documents created in Ubuntu to my Windows drive. I was finally able to execute the command

```
powercfg /h off
```

in a Windows cmd session by choosing the **Run as Administrator** option when executing `cmd.exe`.

This solved the  problem, albeit at the cost of disabling all hibernation options for Windows (including fast restart). I can now only sleep, restart or shut down in all menus and dialogs. Starting Windows takes noticeably longer, but my Windows 8.1 volume mounts fine in the Linux environment.